# Pandas или openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

Хочу написать скрипт， который структурирует экселевские данные ， и размещает их опять в экселе но по-другому (по др. ячейкам).  Что-то вроде сводной таблицы， но с некоторыми дополнениями， т.к. свод. таблица， не совсем выполняет необходимую задачу. К какой библиотеке лучше обратиться к pandas или openpyxl? И какая между ними разница?

Comment: Без примера входных и выходных данных достаточно бесполезно давать вам какие-либо советы. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060). PS и вообще сравнивать `pandas` с `openpyxl` не совсем корректно - это как сравнивать ящик с инструментами с плоскогубцами, которые также находятся в данном ящике. Pandas умеет использовать `openpyxl`, `xlsxwriter`, `xlrd`, `xlwt`, и т.д.

Comment: То есть pandas может все тоже， что и openpyxl и даже больше? Есть таблица с числовыми данными в экселе со стоимостью комунальных услуг по каждой квартире. Нужно выбрать несколько определенных услуг (столбцов)， и переместить их в др экселевский документ， в котором эти данные станут уже не столбцами, а строками и в строго определенные ячейки. Проще говоря，из простой таблицы сделать квитанции по кварплате. К примеру разнести один столбец по разным ячекам в определенном порядке в др таблицу.)

Comment: Не совсем понятно какой ответ вы ожидаете на такой общий вопрос... Вас устроит ответ: используйте pivot_table, crosstab или другой метод в зависимости от того что вы хотите получить на выходе ? ;-)

Comment: Спасибо，вы мне очень помогли!)

Comment: Я не просто так дал вам ссылку в первом комментарии - если бы вы привели в вопросе примеры входных и выходных данных то у вас, скорее всего, уже был бы конкретный ответ)

Comment: Я не очень понимаю， тут же нет возможности загрузить экселевские файлы，если их нет， тогда и объяснить не получиться，  к сожалению((， спасибо вам)

Comment: ссылку на файлообменник никто вам не запретит здесь оставить ... ;)

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/D7hk/NBD7LsW5M  Мне нужно перекинуть цифры из файла "Исходник" в файл "На выходе" и в файл "Квитанция на выходе", только файл "Квитанция на выходе" я сделаю в экселе.  Получается нужно расставить цифры в нужные ячейки. Если я правильно поняла - то мне следует изучить Pandas, а не openpyxl? В квитанции на выходе цифры не соответсвуют исходнику， просто  для примера взяла таблицу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начать реализацию вашей задачи можно так:

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas

# читаем Excel в Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\download\исходник.xls', skiprows=1)

# разворачиваем столбцы в строки
d = df.set_index('Ф.И.О.').stack()

...
```

Получилось:

```
In [34]: d.reset_index()
Out[34]:
          Ф.И.О.                   level_1         0
0    Иванов М.Е.                        кв         1
1    Иванов М.Е.                    пропис         4
2    Иванов М.Е.                      прож         4
3    Иванов М.Е.             Полез площадь      73.5
4    Иванов М.Е.           Отопление тариф   1936.54
5    Иванов М.Е.           Отопление ГгКал   1.66185
6    Иванов М.Е.           Отопление ИТОГО   3218.24
7    Иванов М.Е.    ГВС(горячая вода м.куб        23
8    Иванов М.Е.                ГВС начисл   2689.16
9    Иванов М.Е.  ХВС(холодная вода) м.куб         7
10   Иванов М.Е.                ХВС начисл    125.23
11   Иванов М.Е.              Стоки м. куб        30
12   Иванов М.Е.              Стоки начисл     682.5
13   Иванов М.Е.                     мусор    169.05
14   Иванов М.Е.                  ТО жилья      1617
15   Иванов М.Е.                   ОДН ГВС   0.84735
16   Иванов М.Е.               одн гвс руб   99.0721
17   Иванов М.Е.                   ОДН ХВС  0.766097
18   Иванов М.Е.               одн хвс руб   13.7055
19   Иванов М.Е.                 ОДН СТОКИ   1.61345
..           ...                       ...       ...
165        итого             Полез площадь     397.8
166        итого           Отопление тариф         0
167        итого           Отопление ГгКал   8.99433
168        итого           Отопление ИТОГО   17417.9
169        итого    ГВС(горячая вода м.куб        36
170        итого                ГВС начисл   4209.12
171        итого  ХВС(холодная вода) м.куб        61
172        итого                ХВС начисл   1091.29
173        итого              Стоки начисл   2206.75
174        итого                     мусор    914.94
175        итого                  ТО жилья      7956
176        итого                   ОДН ГВС   4.58607
177        итого               одн гвс руб   536.203
178        итого                   ОДН ХВС    4.1463
179        итого               одн хвс руб   74.1773
180        итого                 ОДН СТОКИ   8.73236
181        итого              однстоки руб   198.661
182        итого                   Кап.рем   2864.16
183        итого                     ИТОГО   37455.7
184        итого                  пени  за         0

[185 rows x 3 columns]
```

Далее после фильтрации нудная и кропотливая работа по формированию нужной вам выходной формы... Для этого возможно придется прибегнуть к низкоуровневому программированию на уровне отдельных ячеек Excel - для этого можно воспользоваться `openpyxl` или `xlsxwriter`.

Comment: Может сразу воспользоваться openpyxl? Тогда pandas и не нужна?

Comment: @user327535, можно и без Pandas, но в Pandas многие вещи делаются гораздо более эффективно и быстрее...